# Passing a string from Rust to C causes a segfault or an error

Tags: c, rust, ffi, dpkg

I'm creating a binding to `libdpkg` in Rust (mostly to learn about Rust FFI) using `rust-bindgen`.

I've encountered a problem at the very beginning of the implementation.

I have the following Rust code:

```rust
#![allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
#![allow(non_camel_case_types)]
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/bindings.rs"));

use std::convert::TryInto;
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::c_char;

pub struct Dpkg {
    program_name: *mut c_char,
    root_directory: Option<*mut c_char>,
}

impl Dpkg {
    pub fn new(program_name: &str, root_directory: Option<&str>) -> Dpkg {
        let dpkg = Dpkg {
            program_name: CString::new(program_name).unwrap().into_raw(),
            root_directory: match root_directory {
                Some(dir) => Some(CString::new(dir).unwrap().into_raw()),
                None => None,
            },
        };

        unsafe {
            dpkg_set_progname(dpkg.program_name);
            push_error_context();

            if let Some(dir) = dpkg.root_directory {
                dpkg_db_set_dir(dir);
            }
            modstatdb_init();
            modstatdb_open(modstatdb_rw_msdbrw_available_readonly);
        }

        dpkg
    }
}

impl Drop for Dpkg {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            pkg_db_reset();
            modstatdb_done();
            modstatdb_shutdown();

            pop_error_context(ehflag_normaltidy.try_into().unwrap());

            let _ = CString::from_raw(self.program_name);
            if let Some(dir) = self.root_directory {
                let _ = CString::from_raw(dir);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have the following integration tests:

```rust
extern crate dpkg;

use dpkg::Dpkg;
use std::mem;

#[test]
fn test_new() {
    let dpkg = Dpkg::new("test", None);
    mem::drop(dpkg);
    let dpkg = Dpkg::new("test2", None);
    mem::drop(dpkg);
}

#[test]
fn test_new2() {
    let dpkg = Dpkg::new("test", None);
    mem::drop(dpkg);
}
```

In the first test, no matter how many times I invoke `Dpkg::new()` everything is in order and works fine.

However, if I execute `Dpkg::new()` in `test_new2()` the result is either a segfault or the following error:

```
test: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 10 package 'fonts-sil-abyssinica':
 'Replaces' field, invalid package name '�': must start with an alphanumeric character
```

I'm not really sure why though.
The following C program runs as expected:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIBDPKG_VOLATILE_API

#include <dpkg/dpkg-db.h>
#include <dpkg/dpkg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void setup_dpkg(const char *program_name, const char *root_directory) {
    dpkg_set_progname(program_name);
    push_error_context();

    if (root_directory != NULL) {
        dpkg_db_set_dir(root_directory);
    }
    modstatdb_init();
    modstatdb_open(msdbrw_available_readonly);
}

void destroy_dpkg() {
    pkg_db_reset();
    modstatdb_done();

    pop_error_context(ehflag_normaltidy);
}

int main() {
    for (int i =0; i < 100; i++) {
        char *program_name = (char*)malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(program_name, "test");
        char *dir = (char*)malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(dir, "/var/lib/dpkg");
        setup_dpkg(program_name, dir);
        printf("%d time!\n", i);
        destroy_dpkg();
        free(program_name);
        free(dir);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0 time!
1 time!
2 time!
3 time!
4 time!
5 time!
6 time!
7 time!
8 time!
9 time!
10 time!
11 time!
12 time!
13 time!
14 time!
15 time!
16 time!
17 time!
18 time!
19 time!
20 time!
21 time!
22 time!
23 time!
24 time!
25 time!
26 time!
27 time!
28 time!
29 time!
30 time!
31 time!
32 time!
33 time!
34 time!
35 time!
36 time!
37 time!
38 time!
39 time!
40 time!
41 time!
42 time!
43 time!
44 time!
45 time!
46 time!
47 time!
48 time!
49 time!
50 time!
51 time!
52 time!
53 time!
54 time!
55 time!
56 time!
57 time!
58 time!
59 time!
60 time!
61 time!
62 time!
63 time!
64 time!
65 time!
66 time!
67 time!
68 time!
69 time!
70 time!
71 time!
72 time!
73 time!
74 time!
75 time!
76 time!
77 time!
78 time!
79 time!
80 time!
81 time!
82 time!
83 time!
84 time!
85 time!
86 time!
87 time!
88 time!
89 time!
90 time!
91 time!
92 time!
93 time!
94 time!
95 time!
96 time!
97 time!
98 time!
99 time!
```

Am I doing something wrong here (which is probable) or is it the Rust test runner which causes such problems?

Comment: you could move out program_name and dir since they are invariant in your loop, and place them on the stack instead of messing with malloc. e.g. `const char program_name[] = "test"; const char dir[] = "/var/lib/dpkg";`

Comment: 1. the C code is not formated 2. "The following C program runs as expected" include the output 3. why the rust code use `into_raw()` there is no point as you don't give the ownership of these `CString` to the api ? 4. Don't cast malloc return 5. always check malloc return 6. always check function return.

Comment: @Anders I know. I wanted to emulate the heap allocations done by CString.

Comment: @Stargateur 1. What do you mean by not formatted 2. Done 3. Because that's the only way it kinda worked in Rust 4. Yeh I just copy/pasted that from somewhere I think 5. Yeh I know I just wanted to quickly test this in C 6. Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Stargateur I'm not sure how to provide a minimally reproducible test case as the segfault/error in question involve interacting with libdpkg and I don't really know if it can be reproduced elsewhere. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not with my code but from the fact that libdpkg is not threadsafe.

This is fine from an implementation perspective but Rust runs the tests in parallel which causes the segfault.